# ISharedPreferences deletes duplicates when inserted

Tags: c#, android, android-sharedpreferences

For example, I have a simple List:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("eg1");
s.Add("eg2");
s.Add("eg3");
s.Add("eg1");
```

Lets say I want to now insert in into my **ISharedPreferences editor** called **editor**:

```
editor.PutStringSet("eg", s);
```

Now, I want to access this list by doing this:

```
ICollection<string> eg= prefs.GetStringSet("eg", (ICollection<string>)new HashSet<string>());
List<string> s2 = eg.ToList<string>();
```

The problem is that I have duplicates like "eg1" in my list but the editor deletes them.

My question is how can I prevent the editor from deleting duplicates in my list?

Comment: The name `PutStringSet` is _highly_ suggestive. Specifically, this behavior is almost certainly intended and you should provide text storage in a different manner.

Comment: @AluanHaddad so what other options do I have to save a list in my application?

Comment: There are many ways I imagine. Why not use a single string instead of a set of set? Also (do not call generic methods with explicit type arguments like that)

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have already tried to use a whole string and than split it but it makes a lot of problems after when the code gets a little more complicated... Also, I dont think its the best thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your current list, you could store also the number of occurrences (or the indexes if they matter to you):

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("eg1:[0, 3]");
s.Add("eg2:[1]");
s.Add("eg3:[2]");
```